# Why is osm2pgrouting not importing?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, postgresql, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I installed pgrouting successfully and did a little import with a 20Mb file. Works good!

Now I'm trying to import a file with the size of a country and it doesn't even start to import. The last 2 lines in the console are: "Trying to load data - Trying to parse data" and then it's done.

Why is it not working like it should? It's not even a out-of-memory bug, it's just not working!

Thanks

Comment: windows or linux?

Comment: linux ubuntu ..

Comment: I think I found the answer.
Installed all the components as last time but this time on a Ubuntu64 machine with over 4GB Ram. Script is running right now. I think, that 32bit OS can't address one consectuvie heavy sized file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with big files (3GB+) - you need to switch to x64 Ubuntu environement.
Problems solved. Works smooth!

Answer (score 1):

Also, depending on your OS, you must increase the maximum amount of 'virtual memory' allowed, or create a large enough swap file (i.e. http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/swap).

Extracting france.osm used 30 gigs in my case...